# LED Current specification query

Tags: led

When choosing an LED Chip for example:3.2V 60mA,I have 2 query..

1) does that mean the LED will draw  60mA ?
If so I can use 150mA instead since it can safely handle more current..

Or

2) LED can handle any current only  upto 60mA above which it will get damaged?

Which is correct?Sometimes I am getting super confused..

Comment: Do not exceed Absolute Max current. Use rated and heatsink if necessary  copper substrate area. Check Rja * VI =T junction rise in specs

Comment: If you provide your LED with exactly 3.2v, it will nominally drain 60 mA. The current is limited by the voltage that you apply to the LED and the choice of the current limiting resistor. For the rest, ensure that you stay within the nominal current value (like Tony pointed out in his comment)

Comment: Simple Ohms Law calc from 5V to Vf of LED for current

Comment: @SimonMarcoux, that is dangerous advice. Very small changes in voltage cause very large changes in current at an LED's normal operating point. Much safer to say that if you supply the LED with a _regulated_ 60mA current, then it will nominally drop 3.2V. Deviation from the nominal behavior will be insignificant if the LED is supplied with constant current. Deviation from the nominal behavior could destroy the device if it is supplied with constant voltage instead.

Comment: @jameslarge I meant protected with a resistor. While it would be possible in theory, each LED is slightly different and you indeed risk buring a lot of them if you don't have some sort of current regulation (either constant current source or most likely a resistor) Since I can't edit the previous comment anymore, I will simply say that your rectification is indeed clearer and will keep that in mind in future explanation.

Comment: @SimonMarcoux. Sorry, I realize now that I never read past your first sentence.

Comment: @jameslarge no foul no arm. It basically meant that it wasn't written properly for a perfect understanding of the principles. I get caught with those type of things when teaching...Hence the reason I take these seriously.

Comment: All LEDs have a tolerance due to variations in ESR above their threshold voltage.  Source selection can reduce thus to single bins of 0.1V tolerance in large custom orders. That’s how I did it for over 10 years. But you may get lucky or not.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheets for LEDs (and most other semiconductors) have an "Abolute Maximum" rating table, with a footnote stating that going beyond those ratings may damage the part.

The datasheet will also have a "Typical Operation" or "Electrical Characteristics" table that shows recommended operation values.

It is best to stick to the Typical values, and keep well away from the Absolute Maximum values.

Comment: Nicely and succinctly put. I'd probably only add that in multiplexing situations higher than "typical" operating currents may be necessary and one may need to also then consider the safe operating zone for pulsed conditions.

Comment: LEDs, in general, do not specify a typical value.  The test current value is often the maximum current for maximum efficacy.  When operating above the test current the lm/W will decrease.  It is not uncommon for a 2 Amp LED to have a test current of 350 mA.

Comment: Efficacy always declines with rising current slightly and more so above test currents which are below abs. Max

Answer (score 1):

LED datasheets usually spec the LED at "Test Current".
Most LED datasheets do not spec a typical current, just test and max.
Most of the time the max current is much more than the test current.
For example a Samsung mid-power LED such as the [LM301B](https://cdn.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2018/05/Data_Sheet_LM301B_CRI90_Rev.3.0.pdf) specs the LED at 65 mA and the max current is 200 mA. A [Cree XP-G3](http://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/dsXPG3.pdf) is spec'd at 350 mA and the max current is 2 amp.
Many LEDs will also spec a pulsed max current.  The referenced LM301B has a 300 mA max for a 10 mS 10% duty cycle PWM signal.

It is best to use the datasheet's IV curve to estimate the forward voltage.

[image]

---

The above curve is for 25°C.  As most LEDs operate above 25° the actual forward voltage will be less than what is on the IV curve. LEDs have a negative temperature coefficient.  Typically the Vf will drop 2-6 mV for each degree over the specified temperature.

[image]
NOTE: Ts is the temperature of the cathode for this LED.

For mid and high power LEDs the simple way to find the *practical* max current is by temperature. If the LED is hot to the touch, the current is too high. The temperature should be warm where you can hold your finger on the LED for a few seconds without discomfort. 40-45°C is a good range to shoot for.

LEDs are best powered by a current source. You can use a current limiting resistor in series with the LED.  When using a resistor it is best when the power supply is just over the LED's max forward voltage. Generally for a single LED a 3.3V supply does very well.

You can use an online calculator to find the resistor given the current and supply voltage:

[image]

*Source:*  [LED Series Resistor Calculator](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php)

---

Comment: Nice answer and a very useful calculator.